# Getting List of YouTube Channel Subscriptions using YouTube Data API V3 in JavaScript

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to get the list of subscriptions of my channel but unfortunately I get errors every time I run my code, I am describing each step below:

`Step 1:`  I created this channel: [My YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLlE_JEV7I0pQ7fhY4BIrrQ)
`Step 2:`  I enabled the `YouTube Data API V3` in `Google Developer Console`
`Step 3:`  I created `API Key` and `Google OAuth 2.0 Client ID`, you can see the following screenshot:
[image: API Key and Google OAuth 2.0]

`Step 4:`  I checked the `YouTube API Reference` and checked some parameters here and got a successful response with all the subscriptions of my channel: [YouTube API Reference for my Channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22subscriberSnippet%2CcontentDetails%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCLlE_JEV7I0pQ7fhY4BIrrQ%22%7D)
`Step 5:`  I copied the following code from the `YouTube API Reference` and placed my own `API Key` and `Google OAuth 2.0 Client ID` after I got a successful response for my channel:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
   /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.subscriptions.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/code-samples#javascript
   */

function authenticate() {
  return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
    .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}
function loadClient() {
gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
    .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}
// Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
function execute() {
return gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.list({
  "part": [
    "subscriberSnippet,contentDetails"
  ],
  "channelId": "UCLlE_JEV7I0pQ7fhY4BIrrQ"
  })
    .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
});
```

`Step 6:`  Then I added the following buttons in my `HTML` code:

```
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

`Step 7:`  When I execute the code, I get the following error messages:

```
Error 1:  

"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or 
authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; 
existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration 
Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more 
information."
```

`Step 8:`  Then I click the `authorize and load` button and `sign in` to my channel and `allow` any requested rights. After that, when I click the `execute` button, then I get the following error:

```
"The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
```

This is worth mentioning that this is my own channel, I login when required and I allow any rights that are requested. I also use my own Google Developer Console account, my own API Key and my own OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I have enabled the YouTube Data API V3 and I have set up everything properly. I can get the proper result from the YouTube API reference but I can't get it using JS.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## error one.

> You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or
> authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead;
> existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration
> Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more
> information.

The code you are using is using the old google sign-in.  You need to change this and use the new Google authorization library [Authorizing for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview)

Error two:

> The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions.

This error is a little harder to understand.   First off when the authorization request pops up it should be asking you to pick a user and then a channel Make sure you select the channel that maps to the channel id you are selecting `UCLlE_JEV7I0pQ7fhY4BIrrQ` The YouTube data api is channel based you only have access to the single channel.

You are also using the `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"` scope and the subscriptions list method documentation says it needs `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions` which doesnt exist so I used `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`, but i would expect a different error message if this was the issue.

Notes:

> I login when required and I allow any rights that are requested.

Make sure its to the correct channel.

> 2. I also use my own Google Developer Console account, my own API Key and my own OAuth 2.0 Client ID. I have enabled the YouTube Data API V3 and I have set up everything properly.

This has nothing to do with your access the client id, and api key just identify your application to Google they dont grant it access to anything.  Thats what authorization is doing.

## YouTube data api QuickStart for [Authorizing for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview)

Here is my QuickStart for this api.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube Data API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>YouTube Data API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '[Redacted]';
    const API_KEY = '[Redacted]';

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube';

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            await listSubscriptions();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print metadata for first 10 Albums.
     */
    async function listSubscriptions() {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await gapi.client.youtube.subscriptions.list({
                'pageSize': 10,
                'part' :[ "snippet,subscriberSnippet,contentDetails" ],
                "channelId": "UCyqzvMN8newXIxyYIkFzPvA",
                'fields': 'items(id,snippet(title))',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
        }
        const subscriptions = response.result.items;
        if (!subscriptions || subscriptions.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No subscriptions found.';
            return;
        }
        // Flatten to string to display
        const output = subscriptions.reduce(
            (str, subscription) => `${str}${subscription.snippet.title} (${subscription.id}\n`,
            'albums:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>
</html>
```